# Customizing template plugin update for CKAN 2.8.2 to CKAN 2.9.5

Tags: ckan

A template plugin previously written for ckan 2.8.2 version does not work stable in ckan version 2.9.5. Are there any ways to update it for ckan 2.9.5? Or do I need to update the template manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from CKAN 2.8.x to 2.9.x is a minor version release but still contains backward-incompatible changes and a major change from Python 2 to Python 3 and Pylons to Flask.

First, you can go over the [Changelog](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/changelog.html#v-2-9-5-2022-01-19) and see what has been changed in the new releases. Then, go over the `Python 3` migration guide https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Python-3-migration-guide-for-extensions and start updating the required changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will review the changes again.

Comment: Awesome. If you still have questions, share them :) Also, if this helped flag it as an answer :)